# Player not colliding with the walls correctly

Tags: java, 2d-games

```
if(x>=Window.WIDTH-WIDTH/2)
{ 
    velX=-velX;
    x=Window.WIDTH-WIDTH;
    System.out.println("x: "+x);
    System.out.println("y: "+y);

}
if(x<0 + WIDTH/2||x<0-WIDTH/2){//good works
    x=0+WIDTH/2;
    velX=-velX;
    System.out.println("x: "+x);
    System.out.println("y: "+y);
}
else{
    x+=velX;
}
if(y>=Window.HIEGHT-HIEGHT){
    y=Window.HIEGHT-HIEGHT;
    velY=-velY;
    System.out.println("hit");
    System.out.println("x: "+x);
    System.out.println("y: "+y);
}
if(y<0 + HIEGHT/2){//good math works
    y=0+HIEGHT/2;velY=-velY;
    System.out.println("x: "+x);
    System.out.println("y: "+y);
}
else{y+=velY;}
```

The ball is supposed to collide with the walls of the the jframe but instead the one that control the out most x and y (ex 800 x 600) go in too far and the ones that control the beginning or x=0 or y=0 bounce to early. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are taking account of the size of the player sprite. If you wanted to detect a collision for a single pixel, this should work. But what if the player actually measures say 100 pixels across and 100 pixels tall? Then you need to actually consider *where* do you want the collision detection to ocur, i.e. right at the edge of the player sprite, at its center, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `x` and `y` are the upper-left corner of the object sprite and `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` its respectly dimension, you could try:

```
if(x >= Window.WIDTH - WIDTH || x <= 0) {
    velX = -velX;
    System.out.println("hit at: (x,y): " + x + "," + y);
} 
x+=velX;

if(y >= Window.HEIGHT - HEIGHT || y <= 0){
    velY = -velY;
    System.out.println("hit at: (x,y): " + x + "," + y);
}
y+=velY;
```

Let me know if it helps:)!

Comment: Nope it stays the same on the "max" x and y sides. It causes skipping on the 0 x and y

Comment: I was assuming that x and y are at the center of your sprite, aren't they?

Comment: Well i think  know why. here take a look at when i draw a box around my x,y. http://gyazo.com/d3b6498a11fb4c982918f751bd796bbe the blue thing is where i drew my x and y in a 10x10 sqaure here is a gif of the collsion http://gyazo.com/75860fa38d5f13582b7ee8308f23fb50

Comment: mmm... It's like the (x,y) coordinate are not at the center of your sprite, maybe is in the upper-left corner... Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: it is look at my previous reply

Comment: so your yellow circle is what are you trying to animate? and that blue dot is where x and y are located?

Comment: Yes that's the physical location of x and y

Comment: mmm... it's like your (x,y) location is not at the center but at the upper-left position of your texture, let me edit the code for this case...

Comment: Thanks I will do it tommrow.